# What does "&" mean in this case?

Tags: php

I know that it's creating a reference in other cases. But what happens here?

```
$crawler = &new MyCrawler();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It creates an instance of MyCrawler and passes the reference for that instance into $crawler. In PHP5 this is assumed so the use of the `&` is deprecated.

See [Object References (the Ampersand)](http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/html/tutorials/tutorials.changes.references.html).

Comment: so if i remove the & it will have the same effect as of php5?

Comment: @noname: Yah it'll still assign as expected.

Answer (score 6):

That is deprecated per the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign)

Comment: More that you shouldn't... deprecated features will ultimately be removed, resulting in broken code.

Comment: ...resulting in DATED code. it's technically not broken UNTIL you update your PHP version but don't bring your code up to date (which is what migration guides are for). The code is not broken if it works as intended in PHP version it was intended for.